# Python include Scrapy from subdirectory

Tags: python, import, scrapy

I would like to know if there's a way that I can put Scrapy into a subdirectory and import it.  I did this with BeautifulSoup, rather than installing it, I just drop the bs4 directory into the directory of my app, and import it:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

In the source that I downloaded from scrapy.org there is no scrapy.py so I tried importing

`from scrapy import *`

This returned a bunch of errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kat\Desktop\linkscrape\cookie.py", line 1, in <module> from scrapy import *
File "C:\Users\Kat\Desktop\linkscrape\scrapy\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import _monkeypatches
File "C:\Users\Kat\Desktop\linkscrape\scrapy\_monkeypatches.py", line 2, in <module>
from six.moves import copyreg
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

Is there any way that I can simply include this to make it easy to migrate the app from computer to computer, or does this have to be installed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. You will hurt yourself.

To achieve easy portability, use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) - it's a golden standard of Python development.

Create a file named [requirements.txt](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) in a root directory of your project, and write all necessary dependencies, like this:

```
python-dateutil==2.4.2
Scrapy==1.0.4
XlsxWriter==0.7.7
```

When you are setting up the environment, create a fresh virtualenv and then simply:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Voilà! You have a working environment.

In case of Scrapy, it's even more important because in production Scrapy is typically deployed using [scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), where having a correct [package](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with a version number and fixed requirements is absolutely necessary.

Comment: This is probably the best/right answer going forward, but I'd still like to know the 'how', so I can understand the 'you will hurt yourself' rather than just be told not to, without understanding why.

Comment: Every Python package has [requirements](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/requirements.txt). Every requirement has its own [requirements](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/setup.py). When you use `pip`, it takes care of dependencies automatically.

Comment: Many Python packages require additional build steps: C extension, Cython, etc. You can't just copy `lxml` source into your project, it won't work. `pip` takes care of building packages automatically.

Comment: There are also reasons of portability, ease of updating, and compatibility with standard tools and services.